# Inserting timestamp value in oracle db timestamp column

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, oracle10g

How to insert data into a timestamp column of oracle db using java controller class in spring?

Comment: what have you done so far? Please provide what you've made so that we can properly assist you

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you haev setup your spring application but it can be as simple as setting a variable before it gets passed to your DB.

e.g.

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

For more detail you need to provide code so that we can assist.

Answer (score 0):

I have included hibernate specific jars in standalone java project. Created UserDetails entity class with userId as primary key and joiningDate as Date object. Then I am populating these values in UserDetails object and trying to save them using hibernate api in Oracle db

```
    UserDetails ud = new UserDetails();
    ud.setUserId(1);
    ud.setJoiningDate(new Date());
    SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(ud);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

UserDetails class variable declaration-
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date joiningDate;